# Android Activity A B C, switching from C to B with intents,

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

I have an android application with three activities the flow is like this

A->B->C

The problem is when i go from Activity C to Activity B.      (  B<-C)

**DETAILS AND BACKGROUND:**

I Have an arraylist of of Albums that contain a list of photos, that contain a list of tags. Activity A deserializes the ArrayList to see if there are any new changes in the ArrayList. Activity A handles adding new albums, after adding albums I serialize the ArrayList, this works. I select an album which takes me to Activity B(Arraylist gets passed to activity B, successfully). In this Activity(B) I can add images. After adding images i serialize the Arraylist. This works, i can switch between activities A and B and the photos get saved. When I select the back button on activity B it takes me to Activity A, I do so by doing the following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{ 
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        case R.id.action_add:
         .
         .
         .
        case:
              etc,
               . 
               .
    }
}
```

(EACH activity has the android back button in the top left hand corner)

```
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In doing so I learned control flow goes into Oncreate() inside of Activity A as though a new instance is being created?

***We are now inside of Activity B***

Now If I select an image it takes me to Activity C.In this Activity(C) I can add multiple Tags. I serialize the ArrayList, then i click the back button taking me to Activity B, now that i am in activity B I click the same photo which then takes me to Activity C, but the tags are not displayed associated to the image, If i hard code tags they show up. But it seems as though the arraylist never gets updated. I don't know where control flow goes Back inside of Activity B, If i choose to take the path with OnCreate() A new instance gets created making my list object null

```
 intent = getIntent();
 arrayList = (ArrayList)intent.getSerializableExtra("key1");
```

becomes null, Since a new instance of Activity B gets created, getting invoked By C ,this ArrayList never gets passed to Activity B, because only Activity A calls B in that fashion right?

**I want Activity C to be able to save the Arraylist properly, When i click the back button taking me to activity B, and re click the same photo i expect to see the tags pertaining to the image**

**Activity A:**

Calls activity B by Intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key1", list); //list is an ArrayList
```

I pass a list to activity B

**Activity B:**

control flow then goes into Oncreate();

This method OnCreate() contains

```
 intent = getIntent();
 arrayList = (ArrayList)intent.getSerializableExtra("key1");
```

I receive the arraylist succesfully.
now I want to pass the list to Activity C

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
```

intent.putExtra("key2", list);

**Activity C**

```
{
```

control flow then goes into Oncreate();

This method OnCreate() contains

```
 intent = getIntent();
 arrayList = (ArrayList)intent.getSerializableExtra("key2");
```

now when i press the back button, i do so by doing this

```
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{ 
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);//control goes to onCreate()??

        case R.id.action_add:
         .
         .
         .
        case:
              etc,
               . 
               .
    }
}
```

Now lets take away NavUtils.NavigateUpFromSameTask(this);

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{ 
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

            finish(); 

        case R.id.action_add:
         .
         .
         .
        case:
              etc,
               . 
               .
    }
}
```

In doing so I get back to Activity B WITHOUT entering onCreate(), but if i click the photo the tags don't show up.

```
}
```

**Still inside of activiy C**

Comment: Try with `startActivityForResult()` to open **ActivityB** and `setResult()` in **ActivityC** to return result?

Comment: Since the arraylist, the data is moved across all the screen and updated. I recommend you create a container class which can be singleton and could be accessed from any where within application. Data will remain persist. Also, the data passed between activites wont be referring same reference.

Comment: @Nigam Patro I tried that but that is bad, Activity C should be responsible for saving the list, If i kill my app in activity C the tags will never been seen or saved as I am relying on Activity B to save it

Comment: @Vinodh If i implement singleton, then at each activity i must deserialize my arraylist to check for any updates correct? and in doing so we fix this problem. Now the way i handle the back button in Activity C (taking me to Activity B) is by just doing    finish() and thats it as flow will not go into onCreate() thinking Activity A called B .

Comment: Why don't you consider adding a global album list object in your Application class? So that you could access and populate the object from anywhere in your project. Also remove items whenever the use ends.

Comment: @JessicaRam : You dont need to deserialize everytime the data. Also, if you want to implement backPress, override onBackPressed(). But, the thing is the reference of data you pass between the screens would be different. the changes you made in activity C will not be reflected in B. As Febi and I said, go for global data or singleton

Comment: @Vinodh Ok I like that  and it is a better implementation that what i am doing, I am new to android and java are there any Singleton articles you recommend?

Comment: there are so many avilable : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm